# How to send messages to all telegram bot users from a list of ids in a database at once using npm library Telegraf

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

i have selected all ids of my telegram bot users from mysql database and want to send messages to them at once.I have tried

```
con.query("SELECT id FROM account",function (err,res) {
           res.forEach(function (message) {
               ctx.telegram.sendMessage(message.id, ctx.message.text)
   })
})
```

but it sends each message to a user at a time.i want to send the message to all users at once using an array of all ids as in telegram api

Comment: Where did you see option to send to many users at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sleep in your loop to send for each user:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function send() {
   con.query("SELECT id FROM account",function (err,res) {
       res.forEach(function (message) {
           ctx.telegram.sendMessage(message.id, ctx.message.text)
           await sleep(2000);
      })
   })
 }
```

Good luck;